# Running a Thread and Runnable Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a small program that takes two classes, a class which extends Thread and a class which implements Runnable.

I've then created a third class where I create an object of both classes, and I want to run the threads and only end the program when both threads are finished.

I've looked at the java docs and am using the .isAlive() function to check if the thread is still alive...
Though this is working for my thread object which extends Thread but doesn't seem to work with the thread which implements Runnable.

```
public class TaskTwo extends Thread {

public void run() { 
    System.out.println("Thread start"); 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("Thread end");
}




public class TaskThree implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Runnable thread start");
    try {
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Runnable thread end");
}



public class TaskFour {
static TaskTwo thread1 = new TaskTwo(); 
static TaskThree thread2 = new TaskThree(); 

public static void main(String[] args) { 

    if (thread1.isAlive() && thread2.isAlive()) { 
        thread1.run(); 
    } else { 
        System.out.println("Threads completed");
    }
}}
```

The error code is in the TaskFour class on the if statement line. Eclipse is telling me to create a method for isAlive() in TaskThree class and i'm unsure why it's working for the Thread and not the Runnable.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance. 
Sam

Comment: Runnable r = new ThreadThree();
Thread theadthree = new Thread(r);

threadthree.start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `isAlive` method in `TaskThree` because it's not a `Thread` -- it's just a class you wrote that implements `Runnable`, and `Runnable` only defines a `run` method.

Querying whether they are alive, then calling `run` is not the way to start threads.  You must have a `Thread` object, and even if you have a `Thread`, [`isAlive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--) won't return `true` unless you've started the `Thread` with the `start` method.

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

You've created a `Thread` by subclassing `Thread` just fine.  But they way you've attempted to create a `Thread` with a `Runnable` is incorrect.  You must create a `Thread` and pass the `Runnable` as an argument to the constructor.

```
static Thread thread2 = new Thread(new TaskThree());
```

You can call `run()` directly, but that doesn't do anything special -- it just calls the method in the current thread.  To start the `Thread`, call `start`, which calls `run()` in a different thread.

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

You wait for a thread to complete by calling its `join()` method, which blocks until the thread completes.

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
System.out.println("Threads completed");
```

Comment: Ah right I understand. Thank you for your help, and thank you to everyone else who commented. It's all appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is you should be calling `Thread.start` not `run`

You can wait for a Thread to complete, by using the [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) method

Answer (score 0):

As it implements TaskThree implements Runnablle which is a interface. you will have to do it this way

```
Runnable r = new ThreadThree();
Thread theadthree = new Thread(r);

threadthree.start();
```

this is should work fine. ThankYou